# Move values in different columns to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, azure-sql-database

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Examples 
(
    Id int not null,
    row1 nvarchar(50) null,
    row2 nvarchar(50) null,
    row3 int null 
)
```

With this sample data:

```
INSERT INTO Examples (id, row1, row2, row3)
VALUES (1, 'Value1', NULL, NULL),
       (1, NULL, 'Value1', NULL),
       (1, NULL, NULL, 28)
```

`Id` is my primary key, and this should be UNIQUE in the table. This is possible for all of my rows, if I simply move all values up to one row in the above example.

I only need to make this work when data looks like it is in the above example. This means that the desired outcome would look like this:

```
VALUES (1, 'Value1', 'Value1', 28)
```

one row, where all the values are moved to one row.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple aggregation, does this work for you?

```
select id, Max(row1) row1, Max(row2) row2, Max(row3) row3
from examples
group by id
```